# .NET Core Automapper different mappings for same types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I am using ASP.NET Core and `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` and initialize Automapper by calling `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));`.

I create my mappings like the following:

```
public class ItemProfile : Profile
{
    public ItemProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ItemDto, Item>();
    }
}
```

I have two methods in my API: One is for create an item and one is for update an item.
I want to use the same DTO for create and update, but ignoring the `itemId` for the create method.

So I try to use `.ForMember(x => x.itemId, option => option.Ignore())` for the create method but not for the update method.

Now I could just create a new mapper instance for each create/update request, but I want to use dependency injection because of performance reasons.
Does anyone have some thought about it and ideas how to handle the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume in the update case, the source ID is going to be non-null or non-zero (depending on whether a string or int ID) and for the create case the ID is going to be null or zero.

If that is a valid guide, you can make your mapping just copy the value across in both cases.

If that is not a good enough guide, you can either set the DTO ID correctly before mapping, and allow the copy across (devolves back to what I said above), or add an additional property to your DTO that specifies whether it's an update or create case, and use that as a condition in your map. Something like this DTO (shown with string ID; you can adapt to an int).

```
class ItemDto
{
    string itemId { get; set; }
    bool IsForCreate { get; set; }
}
```

and this mapping that ignores copy in both cases, but later corrects it after mapping for the update case:

```
.ForMember(x => x.itemId, option => option.Ignore())
.AfterMap((source, dest) => { if (!source.IsForCreate) dest.itemId = source.itemId; });
```

You may argue the latter solution pollutes your DTO, but I would argue "who cares, it's a DTO!" The key is that prior to mapping you have your `IsForCreate` set correctly before mapping.

Answer (score 0):

For different operations, usually multiple DTOs are created.
This method also prevents over-posting or mass assignment by defining stricter DTOs only with fields for which You want the client to provide values.

In Your case there will be CreateItemDto and UpdateItemDto DTOs, which will have different sets of fields and both will be mapped to an iternal entity.

For example:

```csharp
class CreateItemDto
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
}

class UpdateItemDto
{
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
}

class ItemMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public ItemMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CreateItemDto, Item>();
        CreateMap<UpdateItemDto, Item>();
    }
}
```